# how do I use 3rd party Api for example this website(https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v2) into my java code

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, servlets

I want to use api of https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v2 website into my java code. what should I do ?

what are the steps and if possible explain me with the help of code.

Comment: Use a `RestTemplate` from Spring itself.

Answer (score 0):

[Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) is an Android library used to make HTTP requests. It sounds like it would be perfect for what you need. If you are unsure on how to use this or about reading the docs, then [this](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrofit-android-example/) tutorial helped me a great deal when I first started.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8556177/jamwill

I am using normal java

Comment: My mistake. The recommendation for Retrofit still stands. Look through the docs you should find it some use as it is a pretty extensive library. Ignore the tutorial I posted and try to find one that better fits your use-case

Comment: I am learning , Using this website api , I want to create my own code , extract data from this api and display the result in console

Comment: Try this tutorial: https://medium.com/mindorks/android-series-using-retrofit-to-consume-apis-67e047e375d

Comment: can you please write the code and give it to me . It will be very helpful.

Comment: It doesnt work like that here. You need to do some of tthe work.